# Function returning class derivates

Tags: delphi, class, function

I have CObject as main class and CRock, CDesk, CComputer as derivates from CObject. I would like to write a function that reads a class enumeration (integer probably like OBJECT_COMPUTER) and returns the specific type.

Example:

```
function createObject( iType : Integer ) : CObject;
begin
  case iType of
    OBJECT_ROCK : Result := CRock.Create();
    OBJECT_DESK : Result := CDesk.Create(); 
  end;
end;
```

so I can use it like this: myRock := createObject( OBJECT_ROCK );

Now my problem is that the object returned is the main class parent and I can't use Rock functions on 'myRock' without type casting 'createObject( OBJECT_ROCK )' from CObject to CRock and I don't want to have 3 functions for each sub-class. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably come from C++ since you are prefixing classes with C. In Delphi classes are prefixed with the T (of Type). Procedures, Functions, Constructors etc without parameters do not need (). Eg TRock.Create; See also the style guide: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood correct, you'd declare a skeleton of derived functionality on the base class with abstract methods, then override and implement the method in each derived class.

```
type
  CObject = class
    procedure DoIt; virtual; abstract;
  end;
  CRock = class(CObject)
    procedure DoIt; override;
  end;
  CDesk = class(CObject)
    procedure DoIt; override;
  end;


var
  myRock: CObject;
begin
  myRock := createObject(OBJECT_ROCK);
  myRock.DoIt;
  myRock.Free;
end;
```

In the above example, 'DoIt' call on the 'myRock' instance would be correctly resolved to the method of that class.

If this is relevant at all read about abstract methods [here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/methods_xml.html).

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous example, but rather like this. We call it Inheritance, Polymorphism.

```
type
  TcObject = class
    procedure DoIt; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TcRock = class(CObject)
    procedure DoIt; override;
  end;

  TcDesk = class(CObject)
    procedure DoIt; override;
  end;


var
  myRock: TcObject;
begin
  myRock := TcRock.Create;  //Inherits from TcObject and instantiate TcRock class.
  myRock.DoIt; //Will automaticall call TcRock.Doit --Polymorphism
  myRock.Free;
end;
```